# Scalable Gridview Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

I've created a scaling, evenly-spaced gridview layout for a simple card-matching game I made for my nephew. It's behaving pretty much as I want, but it seems that there should be a less convoluted way to achieve this, so I was wondering if anyone could suggest a better/simpler way. I'm brand new to Android, so it's likely I over-engineered this.

I have a setting to control the # of cards (12-32), and it scales to any size screen (tablet or phone of various sizes and resolutions).

Here's my gridview XML:

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@+id/gridview"
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="@drawable/wood"
android:layout_below="@id/score_board"
android:layout_above="@+id/messageparent"
/>
```

I have an ImageAdapter subclass of BaseAdapter, with a getView that looks like this. The getCellWidth and getCellHeight functions return a value I set in the main activity on layout change (see below).

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    CardView imageView;

    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new CardView(mContext,position,mCardFaces[position]); //mThumbIds[position]       
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(((MainActivity)mContext).getCellWidth(), ((MainActivity)mContext).getCellHeight()));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        //imageView.setPadding(R.dimen.card_padding, R.dimen.card_padding, R.dimen.card_padding, R.dimen.card_padding);                     
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        imageView.setImageResource(CardView.CARDBACK);
    } else {
        imageView = (CardView) convertView;

        //If we recycle an old view, make sure it resizes appropriately
        if (imageView.getWidth() != ((MainActivity)mContext).getCellWidth()) {
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(((MainActivity)mContext).getCellWidth(), ((MainActivity)mContext).getCellHeight()));
        }

        if(!mCardFaces[position].equals(imageView.getResID()))
            imageView.updateCard(mCardFaces[position]);
    }

    return imageView;
}
```

Here's the relevant code in my sizeCardsToFit method:

```
//... algorithm to calc cols, width and height to fit screen

gridview.setNumColumns(nCols);
gridview.setColumnWidth(width);

for (int i = 0; i < gridview.getChildCount(); i++) {
    ((CardView)gridview.getChildAt(i)).setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(width,height));
}

mCellHeight=height;
mCellWidth=width;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/MyGrid" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:padding="0dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="2dp" android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
    android:scrollingCache="true" android:smoothScrollbar="true"
    android:clipChildren="true" android:alwaysDrawnWithCache="true"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit" android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#000000">
</GridView>
```